# Replace one line with STDIN in a Makefile

Tags: bash, sed, awk, make

One Makefile target is supposed to be in charge of:

- grabbing the output of `$ perl Markdown.pl src/index.md` (markdown to html)
- using that string to replace one line, something like `CONTENT` originating in the file src/template.html. There's no other line with that row in template.html.

What's an elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like arcege said, don't modify the actual source file. Anyway, this is much easier with `awk`:

```
target:
    awk '{if($$0=="CONTENT"){system("perl Markdown.pl src/index.md")}else{print}}' src/template.html > build/template.html
```

You can put that awk code into a script if you want to make the line look a bit cleaner. (If you do, change `$$0` to `$0`, it's necessary because otherwise the makefile interprets it)

```
target:
    awk -f convert.awk src/template.html > build/template.html
```

Comment: Perfect. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

One rule is that you do ***not*** modify **source** files in a build, so no in-place modifications.  Use a 'build' directory or something similar.

```
template_markdown:
    @mkdir -p build
    cp -p src/template.html build
    (echo /CONTENT/c; perl Markdown.pl src/index.md; echo .; echo w) | ed - build/template.html
```

This should take care of any situation where `perl Markdown.pl` does not emit a period ('.') by itself.

Comment: I think the escaping is off: `make template_markdown` outputs `sed "/CONTENT/s/.*//" src/template.html > build/template.html` and build/template.html is the result of that sed: the row containing "CONTENT" is now just \n.

Comment: Yup, I forgot the 'shell' directive in the variable substitution.  Edited the answer.

Comment: I've `SHELL := /bin/bash` on top, if that matters. Output from second tip: $ make template_markdown 
sed "/CONTENT/s/.*/`perl src/Markdown_1.0.1/Markdown.pl src/index.md`/" src/template.html > build/template.html
sed: 1: "/CONTENT/s/.*/<h1>Proje ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'h'
make: *** [template_markdown] Error 1
$ make --v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.0

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it didn't quite work out for me. Cheers.

Comment: First problem is that your output from perl seems more complex than just replacing a line with text. The second is that it looks like it may be multiple lines, which `sed` doesn't do well as well as say, `ed`.  Editing again to be a little more generic.